# How to test for 'events'using enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have a function, which is something like this:

```
  posXEvent = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    const interval = 20;
    const diff = this.textInput.offsetWidth / total_interval_count;

    let posX = e.pageX - this.textInput.offsetLeft;
     //Do something based on posX
  };
```

I have a component, onclick which the above function is called
like `<div onClick={this.posXEvent} ref={this.textInput} />`

Now I am want to create a test for above functionality using enzyme, however is there a way to pass the 'e properties or pass fake values to test ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use jest's `jest.spyOn(object, methodName)`. For the object pass the instance of your wrapper. For method name you have to pass the name of your class method.

```
const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
const eventSpy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), "posXEvent");

const eventData = { pageX: 3 };

yourElement.simulate('click', eventData);
expect(eventSpy.mock.calls).to.have.length(1);
```